# Code always catches an exception after one failed try when opening serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, try-catch

I found a bug in my code when trying to open a port when it's already open. It throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception at first which is expected. But after that i close the port and try to open it again using my code and it always catches an unknown exception(which is my fourth catch statement).I tried a lot of stuff but nothing seems to work.

```
   if (Button_Port_Open.Text == "Connect")
            {
                DC = true;
                try
                {
                    COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                    COMport.Open();

                    Button_Port_Open.Enabled = false;

                    if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
                    {
                        PictureBox_ConnectedStatus.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
                        Button_Port_Open.Text = "Disconnect";

                        #region EnableBoxes
                        GroupBox_Port_Commands.Enabled = true;
                        groupBox3.Enabled = true;
                        groupBox4.Enabled = true;
                        groupBox7.Enabled = true;
                        groupBox17.Enabled = true;

                        #endregion
                        TextBox_System_Log.Text = "***CONNECTED***" + Environment.NewLine + Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate + " bps" + Environment.NewLine;
                        COMport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        backgroundWorker7.RunWorkerAsync();

                        #region Textbox user input events
                        #endregion
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Port could not be opened!");
                }
                #region Port exceptions
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException SerialException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
                    PictureBox_ConnectedStatus.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
                    COMport = new SerialPort();
                }

                catch (System.IO.IOException SerialException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
                    PictureBox_ConnectedStatus.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
                    COMport = new SerialPort();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException SerialException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
                    PictureBox_ConnectedStatus.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
                    COMport = new SerialPort();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR in Opening Serial Port -- UnKnown ERROR");
                    PictureBox_ConnectedStatus.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
                    COMport = new SerialPort();
                }
                #endregion
            }
```

In my opinion I need to `COMport.Dispose()` after I catch an exception so it clears all of the info inside the object and when I try to connect again it throws new values into it.

Comment: Why dont you check first if the Port is already open, before you try to open it? In that way you would prevent an Exception.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are closing the port.

Comment: I have an else statement which closes the port if it's already been opened using my code. But since it catches an exception the else statement doesn't even get called

Comment: why don't you show the exception in the forth catch? Instead of catch {} use catch(Exception ex) and show ex in messageBox, just like other exceptions. Then you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: Is it opened by another program or yours? If it it opened by your program, how exactly are you closing it after you have created a new SerialPort and lost the reference to the opened one?